# cannot connect 21 port with socket under python

Tags: python, sockets, port

I was learning socket programme and want to connect with 21 port,so i open a software "FTPServer" which use the 21 post,but i still cannot connect 21.
here is the code:

```
import socket
import sys
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      try:
         s.connect(('192.168.199.230',21))
         print 'connect!'
      except socket.error,e:
         print 'cannot connect'
         print e
         sys.exit()
```

the error is 10060,which means timeout
where is the problem?thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you connect to the server using telnet to ensure that it is properly listening for connections?

Comment: Check that the ftp server is running, check that you can connect with a real ftp client, check that you can ping the ip address, and check if there is no firewall in place at both sending and receiving side.

Comment: @mittmemo,Using telnet still cannot make the connection

Comment: @PhilipStuyck,cannot  ping the ip address,what should i do to open 21?

Comment: @evbo is that IP@ even correct ? Are you sure about your network. Check with local IP@ first. On the server where the ftp server is running connect to 127.0.0.1. Next verify the IP@ of the machine.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck,ok,I'm a fool ! I'm a fool ! I'm a fool ! I mistaked! thank you very much! I love you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying with a program check if you are able to connect to the ftp server manually. Any issues with whatever network problem there is, will appear already without you pulling out your hair suspecting your own program.
So go about it step by step:

- check you can ping 192.168.199.230
- check with an ftp client you can connect to 192.168.199.230

if the above does not work, you have to troubleshoot why this does not work first. For instance by checking firewall settings on both client and server machine.

An alternative that makes things easier is to run the ftp server locally first and connect to it using the loopback ip address. (127.0.0.1).
Also in that case you can apply the manual verification. Run the ftp server and connect to it via 127.0.0.1. You can then start developing your client in an easier way and even without a real network and without firewall issues.

Comment: i replace '192.168.199.230'  with '127.0.0.1',it works,but why? if the port is open,i think their results should be the same,or the urls are different?

Comment: Depends, is 192.168.199.230 your local machine ?

Comment: ok,I'm a fool ! I'm a fool ! I'm a fool ! I mistaked!,thank you very much! I love you!